# Is bread a material noun or not

Tags: uncountable-nouns

> I was wondering
>
> Is bread a material noun or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120666/why-is-bread-uncountable-how-do-you-describe-the-three-breads-in-the-picture

Comment: Do  you mean _mass noun_ (which contrasts with _count noun_)? _Material noun_ contrasts with _abstract noun_, if it means anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Counter-intuitively, bread is a material noun.

You cannot use "2 breads" to mean "2 loaves of bread", "2 rolls", "2 buns", "2 slices of bread" etc. etc. etc.  That would be "**some** bread" (1 loaf/slice etc. would be **some** bread too)

---

As with all material nouns, bread can be pluralised when discussing types.  e.g. "2 metals" meaning "2 types of metal (e.g. copper and iron)" but not "2 pieces of metal"

Similarly, 2 breads might mean "some brown bread and some white bread", but **not** "2 loaves of bread".

Also, check out http://ELL.stackexchange.com , probably a more helpful forum for you than here.

Comment: [Two breads please](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22two+breads+please%22)

Comment: @fumblefingers Are you agreeing or disagreeing with this answer?  There's hardly anything there and the first link is a book specifically pointing out how this is a common mistake by Dutch speakers.  https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6UIuWj9fQfQC&pg=PA16&dq=%22two+breads+please%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAWoVChMI_7WYh8z0yAIVhLwaCh0BnQJB#v=onepage&q=%22two%20breads%20please%22&f=false

Comment: I'm disagreeing. This is *ELU*, not ELL (where the question probably should be asked, which is why I've voted to close/migrate). It's not really important whether any of the written instances in my link reflect valid pluralisations. The fact of the matter is *bread* can be used as a countable noun (to mean different *types* of bread, or individual *items* such as Naan breads, and probably other senses).

Comment: You provided a link to a search which returned a bunch of links and books giving examples of incorrect sentences, to point out that 2 breads is in fact correct?  Wouldn't your comment have been more useful and less passive aggressive if you just told me your issue with my answer?  I voted to close as well, just thought it'd be quick to answer anyway.  Hopefully my edit satisfies you.

Comment: I don't see the point in cluttering up ELU with *answered* trivial questions like this, but I've cancelled my downvote.